# Android - XMPPError: jid-malformed - modify

Tags: java, android, ejabberd, smack, xmppframework

I am using smack-android:4.1.0 for chat , i am using openfire. when i am trying to create a account with AccountManager in android i am getting  **jid-malformed**  i have tried all the things but i am not able to find the solution , i am haring my code to create a user.

```
if(connection != null && connection.isConnected()){
                    Log.e("=AccountManager= ","AccountManager");

                    // Registering the user
                    AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.getInstance(connection);
                    //Log.e("=supportsAccountCreation= ","="+accountManager.supportsAccountCreation());
                    //Log.e("=getAccountInstructions= ","="+accountManager.getAccountInstructions());
                    Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<>();
                    attributes.put("email", "kanta@signitysolutions.in");
                                            attributes.put("username", "spota421");

                    if (accountManager!=null&&accountManager.supportsAccountCreation()) {
                        accountManager.sensitiveOperationOverInsecureConnection(true);
                        accountManager.createAccount("spota421", "xxxxx", attributes);
                    }


                }
```

and below is response i am getting in my console , please anyone guides me , what i am doing wrong.

```
 D/SMACK: SENT (0): <iq to='52.62.104.135:9090' id='4Clc6-3' type='get'><query xmlns='jabber:iq:register'></query></iq>
10-02 07:40:21.670 7216-7330/
D/SMACK: RECV (0): <iq type="error" id="4Clc6-3" to="ip-172-31-28-121.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal/8xk12y6kvq" from="52.62.104.135:9090"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:register"/><error code="400" type="modify"><jid-malformed xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq>


org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException$XMPPErrorException: XMPPError: jid-malformed - modify
10-02 07:40:21.675 7216-7216/com.signity.spota W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketCollector.nextResultOrThrow(PacketCollector.java:232)
10-02 07:40:21.675 7216-7216/com.signity.spota W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketCollector.nextResultOrThrow(PacketCollector.java:213)
10-02 07:40:21.675 7216-7216/com.signity.spota W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smackx.iqregister.AccountManager.getRegistrationInfo(AccountManager.java:332)
10-02 07:40:21.675 7216-7216/com.signity.spota W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smackx.iqregister.AccountManager.supportsAccountCreation(AccountManager.java:144)
10-02 07:40:21.675 7216-7216/com.signity.spota W/System.err:     at com.signity.spota.xmpp.CreateConnection.Authenticate(CreateConnection.java:182)
10-02 07:40:21.675 7216-7216/com.signity.spota W/System.err:     at com.signity.spota.xmpp.CreateConnection.access$200(CreateConnection.java:34)
10-02 07:40:21.675 7216-7216/com.signity.spota W/System.err:     at com.signity.spota.xmpp.CreateConnection$connect.onPostExecute(CreateConnection.java:121)
10-02 07:40:21.675 7216-7216/com.signity.spota W/System.err:     at com.signity.spota.xmpp.CreateConnection$connect.onPostExecute(CreateConnection.java:55)
10-02 07:40:21.675 7216-7216/com.signity.spota W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
```

Comment: you can create user using this XMPP Restful Api. read doc i hope you solved.
https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/restapi/readme.html#create-a-user

Comment: ok, but do you know why  i am getting above error ?

Comment: yes, this working solution for me

Answer (score 0):

try this one i hope its work.

```
     if (XMPPConnection != null && XMPPConnection.isConnected()) {
                Log.e("=AccountManager= ", "AccountManager");

                AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.getInstance(XMPPConnection);

                Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<>();

                try {
                    if (accountManager != null && accountManager.supportsAccountCreation()) {
                        accountManager.sensitiveOperationOverInsecureConnection(true);
                        Jid jid = JidCreate.entityBareFrom("spot123" + "@" + "yourOpenFireService As String");
                        accountManager.createAccount(jid.getLocalpartOrNull(), "Spot1234sdfsd", attributes);
                    }
                } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (XmppStringprepException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
```

Comment: you dont need to put any atrribute.

Comment: i am using  
ompile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.6'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.6'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.1.6'

Comment: i am getting can not resolve JidCreate on below line Jid jid = JidCreate.entityBareFrom("spot123" + "@" + "yourOpenFireService As String");

Comment: i have tried this code and getting same error, please can you tell me is there any server settings issue ?

Comment: i don't have much idea about server side.

Answer (score 0):

I am bit late, but you should either escape your JID or you need to remove/replace JID meta character set.